# Does .NET Core 3 support TLS 1.3

Tags: c#, .net, sslstream, tls1.3

I am using .NET Core 3.0 to make a proxy which support only TLS 1.3, I saw that Tls13 = 12288 is defined in SslProtocols. But during my test it only throws exception "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm".
So my question is whether .NET Core 3.0 supports TLS 1.3 now?

I am using visual studio professional 2019 version 16.3.0 preview 3.0, my project is netcore3.0

```
Tls13 is defined in SslProtocols

//
// Summary:
//     Defines the possible versions of System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.
[Flags]
public enum SslProtocols {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Allows the operating system to choose the best protocol to use, and to block
    //     protocols that are not secure. Unless your app has a specific reason not to,
    //     you should use this field.
    None = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the SSL 2.0 protocol. SSL 2.0 has been superseded by the TLS protocol
    //     and is provided for backward compatibility only.
    Ssl2 = 12,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the SSL 3.0 protocol. SSL 3.0 has been superseded by the TLS protocol
    //     and is provided for backward compatibility only.
    Ssl3 = 48,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the TLS 1.0 security protocol. The TLS protocol is defined in IETF
    //     RFC 2246.
    Tls = 192,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Use None instead of Default. Default permits only the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
    //     3.0 or Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0 protocols to be negotiated, and those
    //     options are now considered obsolete. Consequently, Default is not allowed in
    //     many organizations. Despite the name of this field, System.Net.Security.SslStream
    //     does not use it as a default except under special circumstances.
    Default = 240,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the TLS 1.1 security protocol. The TLS protocol is defined in IETF
    //     RFC 4346.
    Tls11 = 768,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the TLS 1.2 security protocol. The TLS protocol is defined in IETF
    //     RFC 5246.
    Tls12 = 3072,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the TLS 1.3 security protocol. The TLS protocol is defined in IETF
    //     RFC 8446.
    Tls13 = 12288
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find this searching online:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0

> TLS 1.3 & OpenSSL 1.1.1 on Linux .NET Core now takes advantage of TLS
> 1.3 support in OpenSSL 1.1.1, when it's available in a given environment. With TLS 1.3:
>
> Connection times are improved with reduced round trips required
> between the client and server. Improved security because of the
> removal of various obsolete and insecure cryptographic algorithms.
> When available, .NET Core 3.0 uses OpenSSL 1.1.1, OpenSSL 1.1.0, or
> OpenSSL 1.0.2 on a Linux system. When OpenSSL 1.1.1 is available, both
> System.Net.Security.SslStream and System.Net.Http.HttpClient types
> will use TLS 1.3 (assuming both the client and server support TLS
> 1.3).

Comment: I think what you are saying is: yes, but only on Linux... (perhaps on Mac as well) and definitely NOT on Windows.