# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: ‘The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, api, ssl

i got this error System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: ‘The SSL connection could not be established
in C# when using this api https://api.codebazan.ir/arz/?type=arz
but when i use this api https://corona.lmao.ninja/v3/covid-19/countries?sort=cases i dont get any error
this is my code

```
 static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string request = "https://api.codebazan.ir/arz/?type=arz";
            HttpResponseMessage apirequest = await client.GetAsync(request);

            string jsonResponse = await apirequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
```

i use window 8.1 and visual studio 2019
any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: And does your PC trust Let's Encrypt certificates?

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  Are you using Core?  This gets complicated.  What works most of the time is to add at beginning of the code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: I think first link is using TLS 1.2 and second link TLS 1.3.  So use OR : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

Comment: i dont know exactly dear @Charlieface how should i check it?

Comment: i checked different types of your code but none of them solved my problem dear @jdweng yes im using .net core anyway i will see this error

Comment: Which version of Core?  There probably an issue with using TLS 1.3.  Microsoft switched from doing TLS in Net to letting the operating System perform the TLS.  So I can't tell if issue is with Net version or the Operating System.

Comment: i use .net core3.1 @jdweng

Comment: Are you using a mobile application on Linux?  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900809/does-net-core-3-support-tls-1-3

Comment: @jdweng no i dont use

Comment: I don't think Windows 8.1 supports the TLS version.  VS is using a new version of Net which lets operating System perform TLS instead of inside Net.  What may work is to use VS 2019 but target older version of Net where TLS is done in Net instead of using Operating System.